# show Select URL box for ClickImageURL in Custom ImageButton

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, imagebutton

I am making a custom ImageButton Control which has the option to show button clicked effect by adding onmouseup and onmousedown javascript code to change image URL. I have constructed the control and it has a **ClickImageUrl** to set the URL of image to be shown when button is clicked..

i wanted to know is there any way i can add a **Select URL** dialog box for my control just like the Dialog box for ImageUrl. is it even possible??? and if so how would i go about doing it...??

any help will be much appreciated.

**EDIT:** based on the answer by Arther i am able to show a Select Image URL diaolog box when i use it to set ClickImageUrl it shows a designer error as :

**Error Rendering Control**
**An unhandled exception has occured**
**'~/images/7.jpg' cannot be set on property 'ClickImageUrl'**

is it conflicting with the ImageUrl ???

Comment: To understand your question correctly: you are talking about the Designer in Visual Studio? Not about a "Select URL" Dialog at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your talking about the VS Designer, then you have to decorate your Property with these Attributes:

```
public class CustomImageButton : System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton
{
    [Editor("System.Web.UI.Design.ImageUrlEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    [UrlProperty]
    public string ClickImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot...works like a charm...but when i use it to set the ClickImageUrl it shows an error in the designer..Error Rendering control..An unhandled exception has occured "~/images/7.jpg" cannot be set on property ClickImageUrl...any idea why it is so...???

Comment: also how did find about this..is it documented somewhere?? bcoz it seems quite hard to remember??

Comment: @Error: Maybe you are doing some work in your setter which could lead to design time errors.
@Find out: Simple: Write ImageButton in your code, then right click -> goto definition. The definition of ImageButton will be shown. Then goto ImageUrl and expand the comments and attributes - here it is!